# How to restrict href link to <oblique> tag

Tags: javascript, css, html

```
<a href="myList/doctor">
  <div>
    <span> The important Info 
       <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mapModal">
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mapModal" 
       id="obliqueIcon">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<oblique 
          class="iconSize">i</oblique></a>
       </a>
    </span>
  </div>
</a>

document.getElementById("obliqueIcon").onclick = function(e) {

  return false; // or use e.stopPropagation() and e.preventDefault()
 }
```

I have the above code.Here the div can be clickable but the 'i' button here should open up a model box (data-target="#mapModal") but it is not since the anchor tag contains the 'href'.

What I am trying to do is let this code should not be changed but when I click on the oblique it should open up a model box but not redirecting to the link.Is there any way to restrict it.Please suggest help.Thanks.

Comment: No such thing as the `<oblique>` tag. Also, nesting links is invalid HTML.

Comment: You tagged as `javascript` - do you _want_ javascript solutions? You could do this with javascript, but feels hacky.  Why not restructure your HTML so the oblique is outside the a tag?

Answer (score 2):

So there are a couple of issues with your HTML: first, there isn't an `<oblique>` tag (did you mean `<i>`?), and second, you can't nest an `<a>` tag within another `<a>`.

That said, though, the more general form of what you're asking for -- a node within a link tag that will not fire that link if clicked -- *is* possible; all you need to do is prevent the click event from bubbling up from that node to the anchor tag:

```js
document.getElementById("foo").onclick = function(e) {
  // open your modal here
  
  return false; // or use e.stopPropagation() and e.preventDefault()
}
```

```html
<a href="https://example.com">
  This should link to the other page...
  <span id="foo">but this should not</span>
</a>
```

Added to the answer in response to comments below:   here's the same code snippet applied to your HTML:

```js
document.getElementById("obliqueIcon").onclick = function(e) {

  return false; // or use e.stopPropagation() and e.preventDefault()
}
```

```html
<a href="myList/doctor">
  <div>
    <span> The important Info 
       <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mapModal">
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mapModal" 
       id="obliqueIcon">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<oblique 
          class="iconSize">i</oblique></a>
       </a>
    </span>
  </div>
</a>
```

I do not get the error message you're reporting ("Cannot set property 'onclick' of null") but at a guess it may be because you're continuing to use invalid HTML (the nested `<a>` tags) -- possibly that's making those nodes inaccessible in some browsers?  (I'll stress that this is only a guess; I don't have a lot of experience working with invalid HTML other than by fixing it, so I don't have a solid understanding of how all browsers might handle it. I've tested Safari, Chrome and FF, all work correctly even with the invalid HTML, but if you're using a different browser perhaps that's the cause.  If you see the error on my second snippet but not on my first snippet, that would confirm the guess.  If you see no errors in either snippet, then you have something else going wrong in your code.)

Comment: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Comment: That error message indicates that you're failing to match the element you're trying to bind the click event to.  Can't tell you why that is without seeing your code.

Comment: You didn't include your javascript, so I can't tell what you're doing wrong with it.  (On the off chance that you're trying to use my example ID "foo" instead of your newly-added ID "obliqueIcon"... use "obliqueIcon".)